# Cannot access webiste running on Apache2 server

Tags: networking, server, apache2, firefox

I have an Apache2 server on Ubuntu 20.04 running a website on `192.168.0.20`. So I tried  `wget 192.168.0.20` on another machine with IP address `192.168.0.19`  which worked fine.

My problem is that I can't open `192.168.0.20` on my Firefox browser. It says *Unable to connect*.
So, I want to understand how to fix the problem.

(By the way, I can open the website on my smartphone, using Firefox.)

I use the default apache2 configuration for the website.
Here are some logs:

- [`/var/log/apache2/error.log`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gpW5dkxnst/)
- [`/var/log/apache2/access.log`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/twKhBf5w5w/)

```
ss -tulpen | grep '80\|443'
```

`tcp    LISTEN  0       511                         *:80                 *:*      ino:45160 sk:6 v6only:0 <->`

Comment: Please add your configuration for this website, the apache logs when you get this "Unable to connect" error message and the output of `ss -tulpen | grep '80\|443'`.

Comment: @BulletBob I use the default config file for apache2 for the default page. Do I need to upload apache2.conf?

Comment: Please add the content of `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: @BulletBob done.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to Firefox 83, which will give a warning when trying to access websites via http and not https. Check your Firefox settings and see if you have  [HTTPS Only](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/) enabled. Since other clients can access your site via HTTP, there's nothing wrong with your apache configuration pre se.